# Trying to sentinel loop this program

Tags: java, loops

```
  switch ( choice )
    {
       case '+':
          System.out.printf( "The answer is: %1$.4f.\n", first + second );
          break;
       case '-':
          System.out.printf( "The answer is: %1$.4f.\n", first - second );
          break;
       case '*':
          System.out.printf( "The answer is: %1$.4f.\n", first * second );
          break;
       case '/':
          if( second != 0 )
            System.out.printf( "The answer is: %1$.4f.\n", first / second );
          else
            System.out.println( "Can't divide by zero." );
          break;
       default :
          System.out.println( "You have entered an invalid operation.  Try again." );
          break;
    }
```

Comment: Edit your code to be unique enough that it will be recognizable if a classmate steals it.  Edit within two minutes and it won't appear in the edit history.

Comment: -1 - if you edit out the question, you largely defeat the point of StackOverflow.

Comment: @Stephen C: then it is a major issue of the SO platform that such an edit is possible, but that is probably a discussion for meta if I understand things correctly ;)

Comment: @NoozNooz42 - disagree, agree.

Comment: A sentinel loop is a loop which is constructed to run infinitely until a sentinel value or condition arises which breaks the loop. In this case, there is no indication of what should be repeated, as this is only a switch statement. As it stands, this question needs more code depicting how choice is collected and where it fits into the overall program, and an actual explanation of what is happening instead of a simple copy paste.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
while (true)
{
    System.out.println("What type of Employee? Enter 'o' for Office " +
    "Clerical, 'f' for Factory, or 's' for Saleperson.  Enter 'x' to exit." );  
    String response= inp.nextLine().toLowerCase();

    // validate input, do you switch statement, return; on x     
}
```

Comment: The switch statement is either inside this loop, or inside another method which is called from inside this loop.

Looking at your code, this while loop would come after you declare the totalPay variable.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `return;` statement to terminate the function

For example:

```
case 'x':
    return;
```

You also need to wrap it all in `while(true) { ... }` to make it loop forever (until `return;`)